# Find a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x \neq 0$, $x_1w_1 + \dots + x_nw_n \approx 0$ and $x \approx z$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-approximation

This is a problem I created to myself but now I can't solve it. Hope you can help me to solve or give some insights.

Fix two vectors $z,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and consider the Euclidian inner product. I want to find another vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x \neq 0$, $x_1w_1 + \dots + x_nw_n$ is as close to zero as possible and $x$ is as close to $z$ as possible. The condition $x_1w_1 + \dots + x_nw_n \approx 0$ ir more relevant, if we have to choose.

My first idea was start finding a vector $x_0$ such that $x_0$ is orthogonal to $w$ and then consider the orthogonal projection of $z$ over $x_0$. This projection is the vector
$$x = \frac{\langle z,x_0 \rangle}{\|x_0\|^2} x_0.$$

This is indeed the vector in the form $\lambda x_0$ closest to $z$. Furthermore, we have that $x_1w_1 + \dots + x_nw_n = \langle x, w \rangle = \langle \lambda x_0,z \rangle = \lambda \langle x_0, w \rangle = 0$.

The problem with this approach is that the distance between $x$ and $z$ is not small in general. I'm willing to relax the condition $x_1w_1 + \dots + x_nw_n = 0$ to $x_1w_1 + \dots + x_nw_n \approx 0$, but I just don't know a method to obtain the desired result.

Comment: You're basically asking to find $\min\limits_{x} \left(\langle x, w\rangle + \|x-z\|\right)$ right?

Comment: This is a good way to rephrase! But there is some way to formalize the preference of $\langle x,w \rangle$ ?

Comment: Let $z_0$ be the projection of $z$ on $w^\perp$. For $\lambda\in [0,1]$, consider $z_\lambda = z_0+\lambda\cdot (z-z_0)$. Note that $z_0$ is closest to $z$ among the vectors that are orthogonal to $w$. I believe that playing with $\lambda$ will give you the answer.

Comment: Levent, that is very nice! I like your idea!

Comment: @Integral you can attach a tuning parameter $\lambda$ and consider the optimization problem $\min\limits_{x} \lambda \langle x,w\rangle + \|x-z\|$ and then make $\lambda$ as big as you want. It is a convex, closed, proper function which is furthermore differentiable so you can just use gradient descent to find the closest approximation.